# Excel VBA - Getting runtime error 1004 - Cannot Access File

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a very simple macro.  I essentially get a data dump monthly for a club I volunteer for of the active members.  I create several separate xls workbooks from that file which I then need to convert to .csv

Here is a sample of the code:

```
' convert Poker

Workbooks.Open fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/xlsx/Poker.xlsx"
ChDir _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv/Poker" & 
".csv" _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWindow.Close


' convert Potluck

Workbooks.Open fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/xlsx/Potluck.xlsx"
ChDir _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv/Potluck" & 
".csv" _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWindow.Close

' convert Pub_Night

Workbooks.Open fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV
Files/Current_Month/xlsx/Pub_Night.xlsx"
ChDir _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
"/Users/birdsdeanger/Documents/CLUB/CSV Files/Current_Month/csv/Pub_Night" &
".csv" _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWindow.Close
```

I run this section of the macro and get the following error:

[image: sample error msg]

If I abort the macro at this point, and manually save-as the csv file into the correct directory, and subsequently delete it and run the macro again... the macro will create the csv in the right directory (poker) and bomb out on the next save as (potluck).

I'll repeat the process with the second file (potluck) (manual save as csv, delete the file from the directory) run the macro again and the first two file are created just fine, and it will bomb out on the third (pubnight)...

Any suggestions as to what is going on or how I can fix the code?  I have to create 18 of these files monthly and I'd like to work the bugs out of my automation so I don't tear my hair when I run this crazy thing.

Comment: Not a cause of the problem (as far as I can see), but why do you do the `ChDir`s?  They shouldn't be needed because you are fully qualifying all your filenames.  BTW - is this meant to be [excel-vba-mac] instead of [excel-vba]?

Comment: IIRC, when you saveAs a CSV file, it only saves one worksheet, probably the ActiveSheet. Is it possible that when you open the Workbook, the ActiveSheet isn't correct? Maybe a blank sheet?

Comment: Yes, it is [excel-vba-mac]. I've gone through a few iterations of the macro and at some point I had added the ChDir to resolve another issue.  I will try a version without it though.

Comment: Yes, the active sheet is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer but one thing I would do first is to record a macro from the user side that will do the same. Then, I would compare my code with the code generated from the recorded macro to see if I could have done any mistake or if I use the right function or attributes for what I need.

I do that a lot of time and usually I find what is wrong pretty quickly.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Export all sheets to separated CSV files. Modify accordingly !

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xCSVFile As String

    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       xWs.Copy
       xTextFile = CurDir & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: = xCSVFile, FileFormat: = xlCSV
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next
End Sub
```